# Track Social Link Shares & Display Them Per Post

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax

I didn't really want to ask here but I'm struggling to work out an issue I'm facing.

I have added social links to my blog which redirect the user to the various social media sites and automatically share the post in question like so:

```
  <div class="social-container">
    <p>SHARE</p>
    <div class="social-choice">
      <a href="http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=<?php the_permalink();?>&t=<?php the_title(); ?>" target="blank"><div class="fb-share"></div></a>
      <a href="http://twitter.com/share?text=<?php the_title(); ?>&url=<?php the_permalink();?>" target="blank"><div class="tw-share"></div></a>
      <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/shareArticle?mini=true&url=<?php the_permalink(); ?>&title=<?php the_title(); ?>&summary=&source=" target="blank"><div class="li-share"></div></a>
      <a href="mailto:?subject=<?php the_title(); ?>&amp;body=Check out this Post from PrintingHub <?php the_permalink(); ?>." target="blank"><div class="em-share"></div></a>
    </div>
  </div>
```

This then displays like so:

[image: Post output on the index.php page]

What I would like to do ideally, is open a connection to the MySQL database and store an integer value every time one of those share links is clicked and then display that value next to the date on the image above.

This would be tracked per post of course.

I have a feeling that a combination of PHP, JavaScript & AJAX would be the best solution but I can't quite wrap my head around it. I have tried a couple of solutions from this site and some others with no luck as yet.

I must be missing something. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: you could preface each link with your own tracker\loger script `<a href="yourscript.php?url=http://www.facebook.....`

Comment: When you say you want to track when the links are clicked, are you trying to track when they are clicked *individually*, or just have a single counter that tracks when **any** of them are clicked?

Comment: You could also add a click event which fires off a secondary ajax call to your tracker `$('.social-choice a').click(function(){ var link = $(this).attr("href"); /* ajax call */})` then parse out `url` from url

Comment: @ObsidianAge Individually per post, so the image above as an individual post would have 100 shares, the 2nd post would have 50 shares etc.

Comment: Sorry, you already mentioned that.